# How to Create a NodeJS http Proxy

Tags: node.js, api, nginx, proxy

I tried proxying my nodejs application running at http://localhost:7000 to domainname.com/api using nginx config but domainname.com/api works perfectly however domainname.com/api/info is not

Here is my nginx config

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name domainname.com

    location /api/ {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:7000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    } }
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the issue. trailing slash is the one required as shown

```
proxy_pass http://localhost:7000/;
```